# Adding while loop user inputs calculations to a list. Python3

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I am using python3 and I have this code where I ask the user for three inputs. then I perform a calculation on them. I would like to keep adding the calculation results to a list. How to do that?

...

```
if choice == '1': #my fist input x
    while True:
        x = int(input('Please insert the number of things you consider yourself a fan of'))
        if x > 0:
            break
        else:
             print('Please insert a number higher than 0')

elif choice == '2': #my second input y
    while True:
        y = int(input('Please insert the number of hobbies you like to do every month'))
        if y % 4 == 0:
            break
        else:
            print('Please insert a valid number')

elif choice == '3': #my third input z
    while True:
        z = int(input('Please insert the number of sports you like'))
        if z > 0:
            break
        else:
            print('Please insert a number higher than 0')

elif choice == '4': #the calculation part
    import math
    def square_root():
        c=(42 * y ** 2)/(z + 1)
        nerd_score=int(x*math.sqrt(c))
        return nerd_score
    print('your nerd score is', square_root())
```

I want the loop to keep going, and each result to be added to the list. until the user exits the loop.

Comment: creating a list i.e.`list = []` and then append your results like this `list.append(result)` I assume that's what you're asking for.

Comment: If I do that I only get one score. Since this is a loop I would like the user to be able to add multiple sets of input(x,y,z) and each result would be added to a list.

Comment: Are you looking to return to the main loop where choice is set and continue to collect the values until 4 is selected? You should expand your code excerpt to include the main loop too so that we have the full picture

Comment: I want to collect three figures and then get the result at 4. Then I want to keep adding results to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, there are two problems you want to solve:

1. loop keep going, util user want to exit the loop
2. add every result to a list

Sample code is here:

```
def loop_calculation(choice):
    # record results in list
    results = []

    # loop keep going, util user input choice 'x' which means exit
    while choice != 'x':
        if choice == '1':  # my fist input x
            while True:
                x = int(input('Please insert the number of things you consider yourself a fan of'))
                if x > 0:
                    break
                else:
                    print('Please insert a number higher than 0')

        elif choice == '2':  # my second input y
            while True:
                y = int(input('Please insert the number of hobbies you like to do every month'))
                if y % 4 == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    print('Please insert a valid number')

        elif choice == '3':  # my third input z
            while True:
                z = int(input('Please insert the number of sports you like'))
                if z > 0:
                    break
                else:
                    print('Please insert a number higher than 0')

        elif choice == '4':  # the calculation part
            import math

            def square_root():
                c = (42 * y ** 2) / (z + 1)
                nerd_score = int(x * math.sqrt(c))
                return nerd_score

            result = square_root()
            print('your nerd score is', result)

            # add each result to list
            results.append(result)

    return results
```

Hope it will help you.